# Use/create/modify variable from separate .cpp file

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

Long story short, I am being asked to:

1. Build a binary search tree, `T1`.
2. Do a postorder traversal of `T1` and, while doing the postorder traversal, insert the nodes into a second binary search tree `T2`

I am having trouble saving those values into `T2` at the same time. I've tried various ways and nothing. I've tried attacking it many ways. I thought I could somehow create `T2` in `main.cpp`, then somehow input the postorder search from the `BST.cpp`, but have failed.

Not sure if I can call and modify a variable from a separate `.cpp` files.

I was hoping maybe one of you can give me advice.

I figured I can just hardcode the result of `T1` into `main.cpp` by creating a new array, but my professor is very picky on following details.

Thanks for any help or advice!

(I've left out anything having to do with `T2` in the code, since it would not compile.)

main.cpp

```
int main() {

int TreeKeys[10] = {50, 76 ,21 , 4, 32, 64, 15, 52, 14, 88};
BST T1;
BST T2;

cout << "Printing T1 before inputing values:\n";

T1.PrintInOrder();


for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    T1.AddLeaf(TreeKeys[i]);
}

cout << "****************" << endl;

cout << "Printing T1 in PostOrder:" << endl;
T1.printPostOrder();
cout << endl;

return 0;
}
```

BST.cpp

```
BST::BST(){
root = NULL;
}

BST::node* BST::CreateLeaf(int key){
node* n = new node;
n->key = key;
n->left = NULL;
n->right = NULL;

return n;
}

void BST::AddLeaf(int key)
{
AddLeafPrivate(key, root);
}

void BST::AddLeafPrivate(int key, node* Ptr)
{
if(root == NULL)
{
    root = CreateLeaf(key);
}

else if(key < Ptr->key)
{
    if(Ptr->left != NULL)
    {
        AddLeafPrivate(key, Ptr->left);
    }
    else
    {
        Ptr->left = CreateLeaf(key);
    }
}

else if(key > Ptr->key)
{
    if(Ptr->right != NULL)
    {
        AddLeafPrivate(key, Ptr->right);
    }
    else
    {
        Ptr->right = CreateLeaf(key);
    }
}
else
{
    cout<< "The key" << key << "has already been added to the tree\n";
}
}

void BST::PrintInOrder()
{
PrintInOrderPrivate(root);
}


//***************************
void BST:: printPostOrder()
{
printPostOrderPrivate(root);
}

void BST:: printPostOrderPrivate(node* Ptr)
{
if(root == NULL)
{
    cout << "Tree is empty" << endl;
    return;
}
if (Ptr != NULL)
{
    printPostOrderPrivate(Ptr-> left);
    printPostOrderPrivate(Ptr->right);
    cout << Ptr->key << " ";
    }
}
```

BST.h

```
class BST
{
private:

struct node
{
    int key;
    node* left;
    node* right;
};

node* root;

void AddLeafPrivate(int key, node* Ptr);
void PrintInOrderPrivate(node* Ptr);
void printPostOrderPrivate(node* Ptr);
void printPreOrderPrivate(node* Ptr);

public:

BST();
node* CreateLeaf(int key);
void AddLeaf(int key);
void PrintInOrder();
void printPostOrder();
void printPreOrder();

};
```

Comment: I think you've misread "do a postorder traversal" as "print the tree in postorder".

Comment: Your are right, but the print was to help me out. By printing, I can verify that i did do the postorder correctly. But I haven't been able to since i'm not sure on how to add the nodes to the T2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables don't exist in files, they exist in *scopes*.

You basically have three solutions:

1) Declare `t2` in `main` and pass it as an output parameter to the function that does the `t1` traversal, e.g.

```
void BST::postOrderTraversal(BST& tree_to_build);
```

2) Declare and build the second tree in the traversal function and return it by value (may involve a copy).

```
BST BST::postOrderTraveral();
```

3) (Ugly) Dyamically allocate a new tree in the traversal function, and return a pointer to it; the object will need to be deleted in `main`.

```
BST* BST::postOrderTraversal();
```